# Product of polynomials with rational coefficients

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have a homework in Algebra taken of Gallian's Contemporary Abstract Algebra
 pag: 303 #48.

Let $ f(x)= a_nx^n + \dots +a_0 $ and $g(x)= b_mx^m +\dots+b_0$ belong to $\mathbb{Q[x]}$ and suppose that $fg$ belong to $\mathbb{Z[x]}$. Prove that $a_ib_j $ is an integer for every $i$ and $j$.

Any hint will be very welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you already know that $\mathbb{Z}$ is integrally closed?

Comment: Do you mean $f\cdot g$? This is not true for the composition of two polynomials, consider $f(x)=x+1/2$ and $g(x)=x-1/2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in Gallian's book. There must be the *product* of $f$ and $g$ instead of composition. In this case you can find a proof [here](http://crazyproject.wordpress.com/2010/12/19/if-the-product-of-two-rational-polynomials-is-an-integer-polynomial-then-the-pairwise-product-of-any-two-coefficients-is-an-integer/).